# Mock reseteasy @MultiPartForm with form with file and other fields

Tags: java, mocking, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using @MultipartForm to upload a file through webservice..

```
 @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response upload(@NotNull @MultipartForm MyPOJO pojo) {code here}

=== POJO

MyPOJO{
 @FormParam("id")
    private String id;


    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    private byte[] fileData;

}
```

In order to mock this I tried to use

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
String url = TestPortProvider.generateURL("myurl");
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);
MultipartFormDataOutput multipartFormDataOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData("file", new FileInputStream(IMAGE_FILE), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(multipartFormDataOutput){};
Response r = target.request().post( Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
```

Problem I have is I have other form fields (id) other than file . My question is how to access these and pass to the URL while testing. Appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for this. Its as simple as calling other form elements using addFormData like

```
multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData("id","value of id", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
```